# Hide user's profile sidebar when guests visits his page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a profile page with a sidebar, but when a user clicks on another user and his profile shows then I don't want to show his sidebar. I've been trying this and some other auth::/@guest combinations but the sidebar is still displayed when I click on another user's profile.

```
@if (Auth::id())
    <div class="left-sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ route('myads') }}">Mina annonser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mina omdömen</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('index', auth()->user()) }}">Min profil</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('editprofile' )}}">Inställningar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Just to confirm, you want to hide the sidebar when a logged-in user visits a page of another user which is not himself?

Comment: Yes exactly, because the sidebar will include personal things which should only be seen by the user himself. So the guests or other logged in users will only see the profile page without the sidebar. And when the logged in user clicks on his own profile link, his sidebar will be displayed

Comment: Well, what you could do is pass the User-ID of the profile in a variable and check with `@if(Auth::user()->id == $profileUserId)` if the IDs are identical and through that display the sidebar

Comment: Thanks man! I will try that out

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to send the id of the user that you are in his/her page
and then you can check that is your logged in in your system and then compare the ids
sth like this

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $profileUserId)
    <div class="left-sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ route('myads') }}">Mina annonser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mina omdömen</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('index', auth()->user()) }}">Min profil</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('editprofile' )}}">Inställningar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I wrote above ;)